# Merging First/Last Name Columns and Changing First Name to Just First Initial

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

A bit of a complicated question here, so I will try to be as precise as possible.

I am working with two different data sets:

1. qb.metrics.df
2. roster.df

I would like to merge the two together. Typically, I would use left_join but there are no similar attributes among the two data sets.

**Here is a look at qb.metrics.df ...**

```
 Rank PlayerPlayerId   PlayerShortName       PlayerAgeExact PassAttemptsPer~ PassingYards CompletionPerce~ PassingTouchdow~
   <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>                    <dbl> <chr>            <chr>        <chr>            <chr>           
 1     1          20889 K. Murray                 23.3 34.6             2375         68.2             17              
 2     2          19801 J. Allen                  24.5 36.4             2873         68.4             21              
 3     3          14536 R. Wilson                 32   37.1             2789         69.8             28              
 4     4          18890 P. Mahomes                25.2 36.6             2687         66.9             25              
 5     5           2593 A. Rodgers                37   34.9             2578         67.8             26              
 6     6           4314 T. Brady                  43.3 38.5             2739         66               23              
 7     7          18857 D. Watson                 25.2 33.4             2539         68.1             18              
 8     8          21681 J. Herbert                22.7 37.6             2333         66.8             19              
 9     9          19781 L. Jackson                23.9 27.4             1762         64               14              
10    10          16497 T. Bridgewater            28   33.1             2544         71.9             13
```

**And here is a look at roster.df ...**

```
 season team  position depth_chart_pos~ jersey_number status full_name first_name last_name birth_date height weight
    <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <chr>                    <int> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     <date>     <chr>  <chr> 
 1   2020 ARI   C        C                           52 Active Mason Co~ Mason      Cole      1996-03-28 6-5    292   
 2   2020 ARI   C        C                           53 Active Lamont G~ Lamont     Gaillard  1996-02-08 6-3    305   
 3   2020 ARI   CB       NB                          33 Active Byron Mu~ Byron      Murphy    1998-01-18 5-11   190   
 4   2020 ARI   CB       NA                          20 Active Prince A~ Prince     Amukamara 1989-06-06 6-0    204   
 5   2020 ARI   CB       NA                          39 Active Jace Whi~ Jace       Whittaker 1995-07-16 5-11   185   
 6   2020 ARI   CB       NA                          27 Injur~ Kevin Pe~ Kevin      Peterson  1994-03-22 5-11   185   
 7   2020 ARI   CB       LCB                         25 Active Johnatha~ Johnathan  Joseph    1984-04-16 5-11   185   
 8   2020 ARI   CB       NA                          23 Injur~ Robert A~ Robert     Alford    1988-10-31 5-10   186   
 9   2020 ARI   CB       LCB                         21 Active Patrick ~ Patrick    Peterson  1990-07-11 6-1    203   
10   2020 ARI   CB       RCB                         20 Active Dre Kirk~ Dre        Kirkpatr~ 1989-10-26 6-2    190
```

I think the way to handle this is to simply edit the 'full_name' column in roster.df to match the 'PlayerShortName' column in qb.metrics.df.

Doing so would require editing the first name to just the first initial and then adding a '.'

Not sure how to go about that.

Any help in doing so would be greatly appreciated. As well, I am more than happy to entertain other ways to go about it.

Comment: Please add the data to your question. Use dput(qb.metrics.df) and dput(roster.df), paste the results in. That way the helper can more easily recreate what you have! Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use regex approach.

```
roster.df <- data.frame(full_name = c('Mason Company' ,'Lamont Great', 'Byron Musk'))
roster.df$PlayerShortName <- sub('(.)\\w+ (\\w+)', '\\1. \\2', roster.df$full_name)

roster.df
#      full_name PlayerShortName
#1 Mason Company      M. Company
#2  Lamont Great        L. Great
#3    Byron Musk         B. Musk
```

Comment: That allowed for the name issue to be resolved. Thank you for that!

However, when I do the left_join as follows:

qb.metrics.df <- qb.metrics.df %>%
  left_join(roster.df, by = c('PlayerShortName' = 'full_name'))

... there are tons of duplicates created in qb.metrics.df

Comment: You should probably add that as a new question.